# How many variations are there of the Avro Lancaster?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, bomber, avro-lancaster

How many different variations of the [Avro Lancaster](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Lancaster) are there?

Answer (score 2):

There were *twenty-three* different variants, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Lancaster#Variants):

**British-built variants (13)**

- Ten combat variants (B.I, B.I Special, B.I (FE), B.II, B.III, B.III Special, B.IV [Lincoln B 1], B.V [Lincoln B 2], B.VI, B.VII)
- Two reconnaissance variants (PR.I, GR.3/MR.3)
- One SAR variant (ASR.III/ASR.3)

**Canadian-built variants (10)**

- Two combat variants (B.X [later 10S/10U], B.XV [Lincoln XV])
- One dual-purpose combat/reconnaissance variant (10BR)
- Three dedicated reconnaissance variants (10AR, 10MR/10MP, 10P)
- One SAR variant (10S&R)
- One trainer variant (10N)
- One drone-mothership variant (10DC)
- One jet-engine testbed variant (10O)

Plus the [Avro Lancastrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Lancastrian), a commercial airliner derived from the Lancaster B.X (the first few Lancastrians were direct conversions of existing B.Xes, although later batches were built as airliners from the start).